# What are the names of the opponents and other features of the Trials?

Tags: scrolls

It is possible to spectate Trials games. There is no direct way to see which trial is being played, but each trial has a unique opponent whose name is visible when spectating. What is the name of the opponent in each trial?

While we're at it, what about other characteristics of each trial that aren't easily discovered except by playing each one?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the names, trials also have some special rules that are often not mentioned in their descriptions:

- You or your opponent may be given some starting resources. This is almost never mentioned.

  This can make a big difference in your strategy, as you will be given a certain number of *each resource in your deck*, so using a multi-resource deck can give you a large advantage.
- Some units may have modified stats. This is sometimes mentioned.
- Some enemy units may not be targetable by spells, enchantments, or abilities. (I did not take note of this when collecting the information, sorry.)

```
Name                 Opponent   Resources  Other unmentioned features
-------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------------------
Tutorial          RobotTutorial 0          

(Easy)                                     
An insult            Nytor      0          
Pile of junk         Chani      0          
Testing ground       Ulf        2 for opp. 
Men at arms          Olivav     0          
Men at war           Athoss     2 for you  
Men of faith         Rakhis     0          
A barrage of bunnies Carlton    0          
Death from above     Gakine     0          
Critter              Ertile     0          
Caller's Boon        Tobiak     5 for both 
Defender of the Cro… Fron       0          Enemy unit has health 6 (+2)
Downhill             Mipi       0
```

```
(Medium)                                   
Energy overload      Morach     3 for both 
Useless              Blunt      0          Enemy initial units have health 10
Keystone             Neash      0          
Maximum wolf         Enir       5 for you  
Feeling fragile      Enigh      0          
Kinfolk VS elder     Ormard     0          Your initial units have countdown 1
A quickie            Kinell     0          
Single File          Ursh-Ursh  0          
Marathon             Vidrio     0          
Hound on the loose   Tetrod     0          Enemy unit has +1 attack +4 health
King of beasts       Noah       0          Enemy unit has +1 health
Wings of Immunity    Shemiak    0          
Metal Wall           Yxob       0          (Units _are_ targetable)
```

```
(Hard)                                     
Mega Ogre            Otrugh     0          
Locked in            Raor       3 for you  
Holy grounds         Bilpon     0          
On the rocks         Noum       0          
Stormy weather       Umithump   0          
A minefield          Peren      0          
One man's pumps...   Yerit      0          
Infamous general     Smoves     0          
Clean swipe          Saygar     3 for you  Enemy initial units variously buffed
Unrelenting foe      Rilis      0          
Poison               Vitriali   0
Pestilence           Imiac      0
Spikes               Machiav    0
Shooting range       Jova       0
Slaying grounds      Bathor     0
Protected area       Gripin     0
They united          Cholt      6 for opp. (Units _are_ targetable)
They returned        Cholt      6 for opp. (Units _are_ targetable)
Big Pointy Teeth     Monty      0          Enemy bunny highly buffed and untargetable
```